# Convertir PDF a TIFF

Tags: java, pdf, tiff, apache-pdfbox

Estoy tratando de convertir un archivo con extensión PDF a TIFF, problema radica en que en algunos casos me transforma bien el documento pdf y en otros lo convierte pero al abrirlo se ve que las letras cambian por unos caracteres raros, no he podido encontrar una solución a este problema en la web.

Este es el código con el que estoy tratando de convertir el archivo.

```
public void convertPDF(File listFile1, File dir) throws Exception {

        PDDocument pddoc;
        pddoc = PDDocument.load(new File(listFile1.toString()));
        BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[pddoc.getNumberOfPages()];
        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) pddoc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(i);
            BufferedImage image;
            image = page.(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 200); //works
            //image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300); // does not work
             images[i] = image;
        }

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir + "\\" + listFile1.getName().substring(0, listFile1.getName().lastIndexOf('.')) + ".tiff");
                RandomAccessOutputStream rout = new FileCacheRandomAccessOutputStream(fos)) {
            ImageParam.ImageParamBuilder builder = ImageParam.getBuilder();
            ImageParam[] param = new ImageParam[1];
            TIFFOptions tiffOptions = new TIFFOptions();
            tiffOptions.setTiffCompression(TiffFieldEnum.Compression.LZW);
            builder.imageOptions(tiffOptions);
            builder.colorType(ImageColorType.FULL_COLOR).ditherMatrix(DitherMatrix.getBayer8x8Diag()).applyDither(true).ditherMethod(DitherMethod.BAYER);
            param[0] = builder.build();
            TIFFTweaker.writeMultipageTIFF(rout, images, param);
        }

        pddoc.close();
    }
```

Este metodo convierte el archivo PDF a TIFF pero necesito que no quede con dichos valores.

Esta es una imagen de como queda al convertir el PDF a TIFF.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El PDF está creado con OCR? Es posible que, si no es así, la conversión esté adivinando qué hay en la imagen y por eso ponga, literalmente, cualquier cosa

Comment: El PDF fue creado con Corel PDF Engine

Comment: Estaba revisando OCR ya que no tenia idea de que significaba, pero ya revise y pude observar que mi pdf si cumple con esta caracteristica

Comment: La línea `page.(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 200);` funciona? No estás invocando ningún método :/  Y lo otro, qué versión de PDFbox estás usando en tu código? (La versión 1.8 tiene el método que dices que no funciona... la 2 ya no)

Comment: Si claro esa linea funciona, la que tengo comentada ahora es la de 200 y utilizo la de 300, migre a la version 2.0.8 y me esta generando este error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fontbox/type1/DamagedFontException`

Comment: Si actualizas PDFBox, actualiza también FontBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El lío seguro está armando las imágenes desde el PDF, seguramente no se está leyendo correctamente y ya teniendo imágenes malas, el armado del TIFF no tiene cómo solucionarlo.

Según las respuestas a [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326562/apache-pdfbox-convert-pdf-to-images) pregunta, depende de la versión de Apache PDFbox que uses.

Para 1.8, la imagen se crea con el convertToImage que tienes comentado

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(pdfFilename), null);
List<PDPage> pdPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
int page = 0;
for (PDPage pdPage : pdPages)
{ 
    ++page;
    BufferedImage bim = pdPage.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300);
    images[i] = bim;
}
document.close();
...
```

Para 2.0 y superior:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilename));
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
{ 
    BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);
    images[i] = bim;
}
document.close();
...
```

Ya después el TIFF sólo va a añadir las imágenes, así que debería construirlo correctamente.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias